# tikzmark not known by TeX Studio

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio

I was wondering if there was an update or something like that in the tikz package, since the tikzlibrary tikzmark is not known by my TeX editor (TeX Studio) .

Here are my imports:

```
%\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\documentclass[handout,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Madrid}

% tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,3d,matrix,calc}
\usetikzlibrary[matrix]
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
% for writing vectors, matrices, tensors in tables
\tikzset{
    matrixstyle/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        draw,
        nodes in empty cells,
        column sep      = -\pgflinewidth,
        row sep         = -\pgflinewidth,
        inner sep = -\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={%
            inner sep=0,outer sep=0,
            draw,
            anchor=center,
            fill=white,
            minimum width=0.7cm,
            minimum height=0.7cm
        }
}}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
```

and here you see, how these imports look in Tex Studio.
You can see that the `tikzmark` library is unkown (the text when placing the mouse on it means: "key not recognized in the options").

[image]

I was wondering why this is the case. I am not 100% sure but I think this happened when I updated all my packages with MikTex, before it was known.

Still, the command works. This is confusing for me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with latex. The syntax coloring is a feature of the editor. It cannot know everything.

Comment: TeXStudio sometimes highlights commands as "unknown" while they are actually correct. If you can compile without errors, you shouldn't worry too much about that.

Comment: The `tikzmark` used in `\usetikzlibrary` should be highlighted ok with [texstudio 3.0.0beta2](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/tag/3.0.0beta2).